# How to add custom details when printing invoice in Magento?

Tags: magento, customization, invoice

I am developing a medicine delivery portal. When I print invoices before delivery, I want to be able to add batch number and expiry date to each of the products listed in the invoice. I will be typing this into each row according to the product. These details have to be included in the generated invoice.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming - at least there's nothing specifically about programming. Perhaps you should either clarify the programming aspect in this question or post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I tried but I did not get an answer there. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: Try reading [ask].